# how to add data in realtime database with phone number?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In android realtime database entry is based on only email password. If someone want to add data by only phone authentication then how it will work. I mean user have only phone number, he authenticated with the phone Number. and now he want to add data by the current authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase provides a way to log in with a phone number [(See this)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth), and provides a unique ID to each user, which then can be used in the Realtime database as the parent key ([See this)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data), and store whatever information you want under it, so that when you need to read the data you can simply find it using the user Firebase Auth key [(See this)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).